# Can &nbsp; be suppressed in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a stylesheet to process RSS / Atom feeds on Dreamwidth.org (a LiveJournal-based blogging site).

One of the feeds I've got insists on prefixing paragraphs with "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Text ..." to create an indented paragraph effect.  I prefer my paragraphs aligning flush with the left of the page.  I *don't* have the ability to rewrite the content or write Javascript to deal with this, and prevailing on arbitrary bloggers to change their habits seems somewhat untenable ...

My understanding of CSS is that HTML entities and characters cannot themselves be used as selectors.

**Update:**  the site I'm styling is here:  http:// dredmorbius.dreamwidth.org/read/

The specific feed in question is James Howard Kunstler's piquantly named blog, and [this entry](http://kunstler.com/clusterfuck-nation/timing-is-not-everything/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+clusterfucknation+%28Clusterfuck+Nation%29) in particular has the non-breaking-space paragraph indents.

For a comparative rendering on DreamWidth see [here](http://james-kunstler-feed.dreamwidth.org/1091.html).

Comment: You can select a single character! `p:first-letter`. I'm not sure though if you can select only a single kind of character only when it is the first of a paragraph or preceded only by the same character(s).

Comment: No you can't surpress `&nbsp;` with CSS. However, if your RSS source consistently uses `&nbsp;`, you *can* try to play with `text-indent: <some negative value>;` to shift the content to the left (assuming LTR).

Comment: Negative margins won't work as that will outdent _other_ feeds.  I've occasionally had some luck mixing and matching properties to achieve effects, but I'm not sure I see a way to do this here.  Some mix of "margin-left: -3em;" and "left: 0;" or something like that (just as a musing -- I strongly suspect that wouldn't work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. HTML entities *are* regular characters, simply expressed in a different HTML syntax, so as far as CSS is concerned they are the same thing and cannot be targeted with a selector.

You're going to have to use `text-indent` in the paragraphs that you're styling and experiment with different negative values to get as close to a perfect reverse indent (or outdent) as possible, depending on the font that the text is being rendered in.

Comment: Given that I don't know of a way to conditionally test for &nbsp; within the paragraph, I suppose I'll just have to live with the indent.  Given the _other_ annoyances I've fixed so far, this is relatively minor, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with fonts, but couldn't you just delete the non-breaking space character from your font (or make it really thin)?

Comment: @Blender: You would have to be able to modify and serve the modified font file.

Comment: @Alohci:  Hrm ... and how would I accomplish that in CSS?  I thought fonts were defined in the HTML (which I can't touch).

Comment: @Dr.EdwardMorbius - Deleted my earlier comment. Wasn't thinking straight. But look into `@font-face`.

Comment: Fonts can be defined using `@font-face` in CSS, but using that for this purpose is far-fetched. And it would make *all* no-break spaces in text disappear, even those that serve a useful purpose.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn:  Thanks.  Not the answer I was hoping for, but a negative answer is sometimes the right one.